# Sky Carousel TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Modernizr.prefixed(a)')

Tags: jquery, wordpress, carousel

the title is explicit .. I don't understand why i get this error.
The url is http://www.beyondline.fr/reveries-litteraires/ 
the carousel is located below "PROCHAINEMENT" title.

Maybe a jQuery/Wordpress conflict ?

Could someone help me to fix this issue ?
Thanks,

Edit : Sometimes (just sometimes) i get this error too : 
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'd.closestItem.index').

Answer (score 2):

'undefind is not a function' means that you are trying to run something as a function that has never been defined. In this case, you are trying to evaluate `Modernizr.prefixed` (you can tell because it has parenthesis directly after it). That means that `Modernizr.prefixed` does not exist.

You will want to remake a custom build of Modernizr that includes it

[image]

> Edit : Sometimes (just sometimes) i get this error too : TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'd.closestItem.index').

That is an unrelated issue, looks like it is in sky carousel based on the snippet you mentioned. It means that in certain situations `d.closestItem` is not defined. You will need to contact the ecreator of that plugin to get more help.

Comment: This answer should be accepted. Helped me with the exact same issue ;]